# Python introspection within IDEs

Tags: python, python-3.x, introspection

I am trying to emulate the behavior of c# extensions for example against a Python class that exposes several properties wrapped with a caching descriptor that return collections of various named tuples.

```
from collections import namedtuple


class Descriptor:
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func
        self.name = func.__name__
        self.__doc__ = func.__doc__

    def __get__(self, ctx, owner=None):
        if ctx is None:
            return self
        result = self.func(ctx)
        setattr(ctx, self.name, result)
        return result


class Container(tuple):
    def __new__(cls, seq):
        return super().__new__(cls, seq)

    def get(self, **kwargs):
        """Gets an item matching the specified criteria.

        :param dict kwargs: One or more key value pairs of criteria to filter with.
        :returns: The first item matching the given criteria or None.

        """

        for item in self:
            if all(getattr(item, k, None) == v for k, v in kwargs.items()):
                return item

    def where(self, **kwargs):
        """Gets all items matching the specified criteria.

        :param dict kwargs: One or more key value pairs of criteria to filter with.
        :returns: All items matching the given criteria or None.

        """

        return Container((x for x in self if all(getattr(x, k, None) == v for k, v in kwargs.items())))


Item = namedtuple('Item', ('foo', 'bar', 'baz'))


class Class:

    @Descriptor
    def prop(self):
        result = [Item(x, x * 10, x * 100) for x in range(5)]
        return Container(result)


c = Class()
for x in c.prop:
    # Properties of Item are not available to introspection.
    print(x.foo, x.bar)

y = c.prop
# Properties of y (get, where) are not available to introspection.
print(y.get(foo=1))
```

When iterating c.prop the base tuples methods should be invoked however the introspection is not present.

The problem with hinting the addition methods of the Container class get/which is that this single class holds various types like a native tuple. Its not useful to create a container with an appropriate doc string for each named tuple.

I am testing in pycharm and ipython. Ipython gleans some insight once the objects have been instantiated after an invocation but that's not sufficient.

How does one build generic containers that facilitate this idea?

Comment: Would [function annotations](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3107/) help? `def get(self, **kwargs: dict) -> tuple:`

Comment: Yes, just as a doc string does with an rtype but that's my issue, that requires either discrete instances of Container for each namedtuple dynamic patching of the doc string.